# How can I use a different namespace class in Doctrine2 targetEntity mapping

Tags: doctrine-orm

When I set a ManytoOne mapping, while both class in same namespace, it works.

but it won't work if the two class are in different namespace?

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="tickets")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $project;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the absolute namespace of your target entity - note the leading backspace in its name.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\OP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="tickets")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $project;
```

Comment: For anyone else finding this, please note the Doctrine docs now specify to omit the leading slash: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone