# Error when targetEntity is in a different bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm getting the following error when I try to do `./app/console doctrine:migrate:diff`:

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                        
  Class VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Here's the line that's causing it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game")
```

Here's the relevant part of my class:

```
<?php

namespace VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\OrderBy;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;
use VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game;

/**
 * VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\Event
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="core_game_id", referencedColumnName="game_id")
     **/
    private $coreGame;
```

What I understand it's saying is not that it can't *find* `VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game`, just that `Game` is not a valid entity. So here's `Game.php`:

```
<?php

namespace VNN\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="games")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Game
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="game_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $homeSchoolId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="home_school_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $homeSchoolId;

    /**
     * @var integer $awaySchoolId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="away_school_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $awaySchoolId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="School")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="home_school_id", referencedColumnName="school_id")
     **/
    private $homeSchool;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="School")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="away_school_id", referencedColumnName="school_id")
     **/
    private $awaySchool;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sport")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sport_id", referencedColumnName="sport_id")
     **/
    private $sport;

    /**
     * @var integer $datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="game_datetime")
     */
    private $datetime;

    /**
     * @var integer $homeScore
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="home_score", type="integer")
     */
    private $homeScore;

    /**
     * @var integer $awayScore
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="away_score", type="integer")
     */
    private $awayScore;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getHomeSchool()
    {
        if ($this->homeSchoolId > 0) {
            return $this->homeSchool;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function getAwaySchool()
    {
        if ($this->awaySchoolId > 0) {
            return $this->awaySchool;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function recordIsValid()
    {
        if (!($this->homeSchoolId > 0)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (!($this->awaySchoolId > 0)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    public function getSport()
    {
        return $this->sport;
    }

    public function getHumanDatetime()
    {
        $date = new \DateTime($this->datetime);
        return $date->format('F d, Y g:ia');
    }

    public function getDatetime()
    {
        $date = new \DateTime($this->datetime);
        return $date->format('m/d/Y g:i:s a');
    }

    public function getOpposingSchoolWithRespectToSchoolName($schoolName)
    {
        if ($schoolName == $this->getHomeSchool()->getName()) {
            return $this->getAwaySchool();
        } else {
            return $this->getHomeSchool();
        }
    }

    public function getHomeScore()
    {
        return $this->homeScore;
    }

    public function getAwayScore()
    {
        return $this->awayScore;
    }
}
```

Why would it not like `Game`?

Update: I had this same exact problem again when I tried to do the same thing with another cross-bundle entity. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688602/how-can-i-use-a-different-namespace-class-in-doctrine2-targetentity-mapping), but the add-a-leading-slash fix didn't do it for me like it evidently did for the OP there.

Comment: Did you try to use "\VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game" instead of "VNN\CoreBundle\Entity\Game"?

Comment: Yeah. It didn't like that, either.

Comment: What version of Symfony and doctrine are you using? I have the same setup in one of my projects, and it works there :/ But I agree with you that it looks like Game is not valid, however, when looking in the doctrine code, that message should only come if the class is not annotated as a Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity, which this one clearly is...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i've successfully used cross bundle entity relations without any problems. if you have automatic mapping disabled you need to tell doctrine each bundle that contains entities.

so in app/config.yml you need to have either this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

or this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: false
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    VNNCoreBundle: ~
                    VNNPressboxBundle: ~
```

check your database if tables for the bundles exist. also you could try running `./app/console doctrine:generate:entities --force` and make sure it runs without errors

**edit**

i checked my code and the leading `/` is not necessary. also the `use` statement is superfluous.

Comment: This seems to have worked. I have a vague memory of having a reason not to use `auto_mapping`, so I tried your second suggestion of making sure each of my mappings are explicitly listed. I'm getting a different error now - it's looking in the wrong database - but that error is much easier to swallow than what I was getting before. Thanks!

Comment: have the same vague memory about not using the auto mapping... it might have to do something with the doctrine extensions but am not sure ;)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get something like this to work in my bundles.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Company\SomeBundle\Entity\Game")
 */
```

You do not need the `use \Company\SomeBundle\Entity\Game` statement.

Also, make sure both bundles are enabled in your `AppKernel.php` file.